# RxJava - forward result of flatMap operator to a later point in chain

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I'm developing a cars card game which allows you to create an account and own some cards of cars. Basically every new created account on the server already owns some cards. In the following code I'm creating an account and am persisting it in the database with the ids of the owned cars as well.

```
private Observable<Account> createAccount() {
    return AccountService.createAccount()
            .flatMap(account -> persistAccount(account))
            .flatMap(account -> persistOwnedCarsFromServer(account));
}

private Observable<Account> persistAccount(final Account account) {
    ... persist account ...
    return Observable.just(account);
}

private Observable<Account> persistOwnedCars(final Account account) {
    return AccountService.getOwnedCarIds()
            .flatMap(carIds -> persistOwnedCarIds(account.mId, carIds))
            .flatMap(carsIds -> Observable.just(account)); // don't like this line
}

private Observable<List<Integer>> persistOwnedCarIds(final int accountId, final List<Integer> ownedCarIds){
    ... persist car ids together with accountId ...
    return return Observable.just(ownedCarIds);
}
```

The problem I have with this code is the last line in `persistOwnedCars()`. I would rather delete this line and let the method return an `Observable<List<Integer>>` as result, so I can use it in some other place as well. So actually I would like to achieve something like this in the `createAccount()` method:

```
private Observable<Account> createAccount() {
    return AccountService.createAccount()
            .flatMap(account -> persistAccount(account)) // returns Observable<Account>
            .flatMap(account -> persistOwnedCarsFromServer(account)) // returns Observable<List<Integer>>
            .magic(carIds -> returnAccountFromAbove()); // returns Observable<Account> 
}
```

Is there a way to somehow forward the result of a `flatMap operator` to a later point in the chain? Or is there a better way to achieve this whole stuff in general? Thanks!

Comment: You can always wrap intermediate results in another object (maybe just a `Pair`) and unpack them later on when you need them...

Comment: instead of `flatMap`, you can use `map` (ie: `.flatMap(account -> persist(account)).map(carIds -> account)`) I don't know other approach.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, your best option is to map the results back to the account type, perhaps via the help of a Pair class if you need both the account and the List later on:

```
AccountService.createAccount()
   .flatMap(account -> persistAccount(account))
   .flatMap(account -> 
        persistOwnedCarsFromServer(account).map(v -> Pair.of(account, v)) 
   .flatMap(pair -> processList(pair.second).map(v -> v.first));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing *side effects*. I would guess that `persistX` is an I/O operation, which is often viewed as a side-effect. Have you already considered using the [`doOnNext`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnNext(rx.functions.Action1)) here? This might benefit you if you do not change the `account` itself but only use the data in this object to write to database, file or whatever and then return *the same object*. This might be useful for both the `persistAccount` as well as the `persistOwnedCars`.

```
AccountService.createAccount()
    .doOnNext(account -> persistAccount(account))
    .doOnNext(account -> persistOwnedCars(account));

private void persistAccount(final Account account) {
    // write to database
    // ...
}

// other methods like persistOwnedCars and persistOwnedCarIds here...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this from vzsg when i had a similar problem in RxSwift.

```
getFoo().flatMap { foo in
    getBars(ofFoo: foo.id).map { bars in (foo, bars) }
}
```